# tikz-Graph problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following graph which I defined:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n1) at (1,10) {(D,D)};
  \node (n2) at (3,8)  {(D,A)};
  \node (n3) at (5,6)  {(D,N)};
  \node (n4) at (7,4) {(D,O)};
  \node (n5) at (7,2)  {\sout{(A,D)}};
  \node (n6) at (5,0)  {(A,A)};
  \node (n7) at (3,-2)  {(A,N)};
  \node (n8) at (1,-4)  {(A,O)};
  \node (n9) at (-1,-4)  {\sout{(N,D)}};
  \node (n10) at (-3,-2)  {\sout{(N,A)}};
  \node (n11) at (-5,0)  {(N,N)};
  \node (n12) at (-7,2)  {(N,O)};
  \node (n13) at (-7,4)  {(O,D)};
  \node (n14) at (-5,6)  {(O,A)};
  \node (n15) at (-3,8)  {(O,N)};
  \node (n16) at (-1,10)  {(O,O)};

 \path[->, every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]

    (n1)    edge [bend right]  (n4) 
            edge [bend right]  (n3) 
            edge [bend right]  (n2) 

    (n2)    edge   (n6) 
            edge   (n7) 
            edge   (n8) 

    (n3)    edge   (n11) 
            edge   (n12) 

    (n4)    edge   (n13) 
            edge   (n14) 
            edge   (n15) 
            edge [bend left]  (n16) 

    (n6) edge [bend right]  (n7) 
         edge [bend right]  (n8)


    (n7)    edge   (n11) 
            edge   (n12) 

    (n8)    edge   (n13) 
            edge   (n14) 
            edge   (n15) 
            edge   (n16) 

    (n12)    edge   (n13) 
            edge [bend right]  (n14) 
            edge [bend right]  (n15) 
            edge [bend right]  (n16) 

    (n13)    edge [bend right]  (n1) 
            edge   (n2) 
            edge   (n3) 
            edge   (n4) 

    (n14)    edge   (n6) 
            edge   (n7) 
            edge [bend left]  (n8) 

    (n15)    edge   (n11) 
            edge [bend left]  (n12) 

    (n16) edge [bend left]  (n13) 
          edge [bend left]  (n14) 
          edge [bend left]  (n15) 

%selflloops for better graphic display:
(n1)  edge [loop above] node  (n1) 

(n6)  edge [loop below] node  (n6)

(n11) edge [loop below] node  (n11)

(n16) edge [loop above] node  (n16)
%   (n11) edge [bend right] node  (n14)
%cannot be added????
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph with the possible states which could be reached.}
\end{figure}
```

But somehow I get the errors:

```
! Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, or node expected.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.471 }


! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Could somebody plz give me a hint how I could solve the paths properly?

Comment: At the end of your code nodes need `{}`

Comment: For solvers: +`\usepackage{ulem}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to the selfloops: You tried to refer to its own nodes in an unusual way. I enclose the source code and a preview of the result.

```
%! *latex tikz-path.tex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n1) at (1,10) {(D,D)};
  \node (n2) at (3,8)  {(D,A)};
  \node (n3) at (5,6)  {(D,N)};
  \node (n4) at (7,4) {(D,O)};
  \node (n5) at (7,2)  {\sout{(A,D)}};
  \node (n6) at (5,0)  {(A,A)};
  \node (n7) at (3,-2)  {(A,N)};
  \node (n8) at (1,-4)  {(A,O)};
  \node (n9) at (-1,-4)  {\sout{(N,D)}};
  \node (n10) at (-3,-2)  {\sout{(N,A)}};
  \node (n11) at (-5,0)  {(N,N)};
  \node (n12) at (-7,2)  {(N,O)};
  \node (n13) at (-7,4)  {(O,D)};
  \node (n14) at (-5,6)  {(O,A)};
  \node (n15) at (-3,8)  {(O,N)};
  \node (n16) at (-1,10)  {(O,O)};

 \path[->, every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (n1)    edge [bend right]  (n4) 
            edge [bend right]  (n3) 
            edge [bend right]  (n2) 
    (n2)    edge   (n6) 
            edge   (n7) 
            edge   (n8) 
    (n3)    edge   (n11) 
            edge   (n12) 
    (n4)    edge   (n13) 
            edge   (n14) 
            edge   (n15) 
            edge [bend left]  (n16) 
    (n6) edge [bend right]  (n7) 
         edge [bend right]  (n8)
    (n7)    edge   (n11) 
            edge   (n12) 
    (n8)    edge   (n13) 
            edge   (n14) 
            edge   (n15) 
            edge   (n16) 
    (n12)    edge   (n13) 
            edge [bend right]  (n14) 
            edge [bend right]  (n15) 
            edge [bend right]  (n16) 
    (n13)    edge [bend right]  (n1) 
            edge   (n2) 
            edge   (n3) 
            edge   (n4) 
    (n14)    edge   (n6) 
            edge   (n7) 
            edge [bend left]  (n8) 
    (n15)    edge   (n11) 
            edge [bend left]  (n12) 
    (n16) edge [bend left]  (n13) 
          edge [bend left]  (n14) 
          edge [bend left]  (n15) 
%selflloops for better graphic display:
(n1)  edge [loop above] (n1) %{}
(n6)  edge [loop below] (n6) %node  (n6) {}
(n11) edge [loop below] (n11) %node  (n11) {}
(n16) edge [loop above] (n16) %node  (n16) {}
(n11) edge [bend right] (n14);  %node  (n14) {};
%cannot be added???? It can.
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph with the possible states which could be reached.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Thx a lot - this I wouldn't have spotted out - at least not within reasonable time. Great :) You saved my day THX :)

Comment: You are welcome, dear @LeO, it has been my pleasure to help you.